# Can't run two different animate functions

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, jquery-animate

**EDIT :**
Ok, I got it. Really sorry and thanks to Anthony, Rakesh and Nidhin :) The problem was because of my sign "+" in the toTheLeft function :

$( "#inner" ).animate({'left': '**+**'+ newLeft +'px'}, 'fast' );

-----------------------------------^

I'm working on a system to show videos in a row (like a playlist) and I want the user to be able to clic on a right/left arrow to show hidden videos from playlist. Quite like vimeo.com

The problem is that, I have two "animate functions" and if I click more than 2 or 3 times on the right arrow I can't click on the left arrow anymore. I mean, it doesn't animate anything.

Here is my JS code :

```
function toTheLeft(){
        var posLeft = $("#inner").position().left;
        var liWidth = $( ".list" ).outerWidth( true );
        var nLeft   = (liWidth+posLeft);
        if(nLeft > '0') { 
            var newLeft = '0'; 
        } else { 
            var newLeft = nLeft; 
        }
        $( "#inner" ).animate({'left': '+'+ newLeft +'px'}, 'fast' );
    }

    function toTheRight(){
        var posLeft = $("#inner").position().left;
        var liWidth = $( ".list" ).outerWidth( true );
        var inWidth = $("#inner").outerWidth( true ); // get width;
        var posRight = (inWidth + posLeft); // add the two together

        var vWidth  = $("#videos").outerWidth( true );
        var newLeft = (liWidth-posLeft);

        if(posRight > vWidth) {
            $( "#inner" ).animate({'left': '-'+ newLeft +'px'}, 'fast');
        }

    }
$("#left").on( "click", toTheLeft );

$("#right").on( "click", toTheRight );
```

The html code is only two divs #right and #left. Everything works until I click like 2 or 3 times. The div #videos shows like 5 videos and the #inner contains 10 videos (or more).

Thanks, in advance. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: you have defined "var newLeft" three times. No need. Just define "var newLeft" outside of if condition and than try

Comment: newLeft depends on posLeft which changes each time I click on an arrow. So I have to define it each time the function runs.

Comment: that's fine...so you can define newLeft globally  and use the different value of newLeft in different function.

Comment: Thanks, it will sounds dumb but how do I do that ? :) sorry, still new in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `stop()` to stop a running animation.

`$( "#inner" ).stop().animate({'left': '+'+ newLeft +'px'}, 'fast' );`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work :(. And I verified. It blocks if I click two times on the same arrow. But if I click on the right arrow and then on the left arrow it works without any problem. I really don't understand.

Comment: Maybe a little more HTML code would be helpful. Are you sure that you don't have double IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your left value is not changing.. 
check the console of this fiddle..
Your left value remains the same..

```
 var posLeft = $("#inner").position().left;
    var liWidth = $( ".list" ).outerWidth( true );
    var inWidth = $("#inner").outerWidth( true ); // get width;
    var posRight = (inWidth + posLeft); // add the two together

    var vWidth  = $("#videos").outerWidth( true );
    var newLeft = (liWidth-posLeft);
```

there is no value change in this

check this jsfiddle with ur console open
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TSK55/)